# Vector objects pasted into Photoshop as 'Smart objects' do not seem to be fully 'smart'

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, smartobject

From what I've been reading (e.g. [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-video-animation-layers-photoshop.html)) I should be able to animate the scaling of a layer in Photoshop CC 2018's Timeline, provided the layer is a **smart object**. Once an object is a smart object the 'Position' option for that layer in the timeline should change to 'Transform'. Okay, that makes sense.

However, when I copy and pasted some artwork from Illustrator into Photoshop, I chose for it be pasted *as* a smart object. It has a 'Smart' icon in the layers panel. But examining that object in the timeline shows that it only has the 'Position' option, not 'Transform'. To make Transform available I have to select the layer in the Layer panel and choose 'Convert to Smart Object', sort of double-smartening it.

Why does vector artwork pasted as a smart object not gain full 'smart object' privileges without this doubling-up process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Vector Smart Objects* have limitations regarding transformations, I suppose due to the fact that their main functionality is that they can be edited in Illustrator. On the other side, the *Photoshop Smart Object* does not have these limitations, that's why the double action.

> If you have a Smart Object made from a Photoshop document or object on a layer, you can warp it any way you like. However, if the Smart Object is a Vector Smart Object from Illustrator, you cannot warp it.

[Extracted from here](http://planetphotoshop.com/smart-object-warp.html)

The transformation is made on the *Photoshop Smart Object* and then, by double clicking, it's possible to access the *Vector Smart Object* to double click and edit it in Illustrator.

The conclusion is that a *Vector Smart Object* is not the same as a *Photoshop Smart Object*.